# Can substring expansion be used in dash shell or bourne shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, ubuntu

I'm converting an app to a new image, and the existing commands use substring expansion to set the artifact version like so: `mvn clean versions:set -DnewVersion="0.1.$VCSINFO.I${INFO:0:6}.M$OTHER_INFO"`.  I'm using a ubuntu image that defaults to `/bin/sh`, and I am unable to figure out how to either do something equivalent in bourne shell, or switch shells to run the command.  I know bash is installed because I can see it in `/etc/shells`.

I tried using `RUN ['/bin/bash', '-c', '...']` but I can see it is just running that command like so `The command '/bin/sh -c ['/bin/bash', '-c',...`. What is the best way to convert this functionality over to this new image?

Comment: Did you bother looking at the man-pages? Or did you give these shells only as an example, and are really interested whether you can use this feature in a Posix-compatible shell (as your _shell_ tag suggests)? In the latter case, you can find the answer in the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Comment: If you're trying to use the JSON-array syntax of `RUN`, `CMD`, or `ENTRYPOINT`, it must be a valid JSON array with double quotes.  `${A:B:C}` is not one of the standard Bourne shell variable expansions; they are listed out in @user1934428's link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a bash command in two ways, even from sh: Either by passing the string '/bin/bash path/to/your/cmd' to the -c option of sh, or by setting the x-bit in cmd and having as the first line in cmd a `#!/bin/bash`.

Hence in your setting I would try either a `RUN ['/bin/bash /path/to/your/cmd']` or just do a `RUN ['/path/to/your/cmd']` and ensure that `cmd` has the `#!` line mentioned above, or  complicated but fail safe - write a sh wrapper script, which then invokes the bash script in turn. Hence, if this wrappe script is called `/path/to/your/cmdwrapper.sh`, its content would be

```sh
:
/bin/bash /path/to/your/cmd
```